# Tunnelling difference over VXLAN vs NVGRE vs GENEVE

Tags: linux, network-core, tunnel, gre, vxlan

Any bullet points that are most imp points when it comes differences between these three tunnellings VXLAN/NVGRE/GENEVE in networks.

Found some notes here, anything that you may like to add would be great.

https://msandbu.wordpress.com/2015/12/03/software-defined-networking-difference-between-vxlan-and-nvgre/